# How top stop PHP recursion?

Tags: php, recursion

Let's say I have function that calls itself recursivly 3 times for example:

```
function recursion($n=1){
   if($n<3){
     echo 1;
       recursion($n+1);
   }
    echo 2; 
}
```

It must print 11222. But can I do something on last iteration to prevent previously iterations, to get 11? Im looking for any solution.

Comment: _Prevent previous iterations???_ How can you prevent what has already happened? Or am I misunderstanding the question

Comment: You could return something from this function and only do the last `echo 2;` if this flag allows it to.

Comment: The function will only output `112`. On first iteration `1 < 3` so it prints `1`. On second iteration, `n=2` and `2 < 3` so it prints `1` and calls itself again. On the third iteration `n=3` and `3 !< 3` so it prints` 2` and exits.
 
Concerning your question. It is not really clear what you want to achieve here.

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah, its incorrect question, and also i didnt fully explain it, i just edited my question

Comment: Please revert your edit! Questions should aim to be a [mcve]! Your previous version was much better

Comment: @David Stockinger i think this question was incorrectly formed and didnt explain what I want to do, maybe I must delete this one and create new?

Comment: No, your question is fine and you already have two answers which explain the problem - one from me, which explains why the function misbehaves

Comment: @DavidStockinger I am sorry, but I didn't get how to make this with 2 functions

Comment: If you have a problem with 2 functions and recursion, ask a new question and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code is misbehaving is because your `recursing()` function is flawed.

Whenever you call a function, it gets placed on the stack. When the function finishes, it gets popped off the stack and returns to the caller.

In your example, `recursion()` checks to see if `n < 3`, then prints "1" and calls `recursion()` with `n+1`. However, the function doesn't stop there. It still runs!

After `recursion()` is being called with `n = 3`, the instruction pointer gets back to where the previous call to `recursion()` was being made, and continues. And what do you tell it to continue with? Well, printing "2" of course.

## The Solution

```
function recursion($n=1){
    if($n<3){
        echo 1;
        recursion($n+1);
    }
    else {
        echo 2;
    }
}
```